# button to remove line item from sales order using suite script 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I had two buttons in my sales order "add" and "remove"
I need to add items to the sales order by clicking that button and needed to remove the entered items by clicking the remove button. I actually completed the first part that is adding button enter items to the sales order. now I am working on removing items from it. I had added the remove button using user event script and working on the client script to remove items from the sales order.is there anyone who can help me??

Answer (score 1):

In client script:

```
currentRecord.removeLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: LINE_NO });
```

Using workflow:

```
define(['N/record'], function (record) {
```

function onAction(context) {
    var newRecord = context.newRecord;

```
var rec = record.load({ type: newRecord.type, id: newRecord.id, isDynamic: true });

rec.removeLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: LINE_NO });

return rec.save();
```

}

return {
    onAction: onAction
  }
});

Comment: but this code can remove only particular item in that line. but I needed to remove items that are added using the add button

Comment: You will need to set a flag or some identifier or line# through which you can identify the line